# How to generate script to add single column using SMO with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I want to use SMO to generate scripts to add some columns to a table.

The expected script should be similar to :

```
ALTER TABLE [Table_Test]
ADD [Column_Test] [int] NULL
```

In the case of Indexes I am able to generate the create script using

```
  ScriptingOptions create = new ScriptingOptions
    {
         ScriptForCreateOrAlter = true,
         IncludeIfNotExists = true
    };   


  Index newDestinationIndex = new Index(destinationTable, name)
            {
                IndexKeyType = srcind.IndexKeyType,
                IsClustered = srcind.IsClustered,
                IsUnique = srcind.IsUnique,
                CompactLargeObjects = srcind.CompactLargeObjects,
                IgnoreDuplicateKeys = srcind.IgnoreDuplicateKeys,
                IsFullTextKey = srcind.IsFullTextKey,
                PadIndex = srcind.PadIndex,
                FileGroup = srcind.FileGroup,
                FillFactor = srcind.FillFactor
            };


   newDestinationIndex.Script(create);
```

I have seen Column object contains the method ScriptCreate but it is internal override

How I can generate the script to alter a table to add a new column?
Object Column of SMO doesn't have a method Script().

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a programming task involving  SQL Server, think "I know, I'll use SMO". Now they have two problems. Any reason you don't just execute the `ALTER` statement you know you'll need anyway? Jumping through hoops to make SMO produce doesn't seem to gain you anything here.

Comment: I'm going to echo @JeroenMostert's sentiment. SMO generates and executes TSQL on the back end. OTOH, SMO exists for a reason. TL;DR - as is often the case, "use the right tool for the job" applies.

Comment: I am just posting a small part of the full process, my mistake to not provide full information. I can't know the ALTER statement because should be generated dynamically, We need to scan some tables and generate other tables with some of the columns in runtime. Of course i can execute the ALTER statement but I don't want to write a helper that scan a table and their columns and generate manually an ALTER statement in c#, for this already exist SMO.
As I said before my mistake to not provide full information of my use case